# Embedding HTML tags into ASP.Net page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to convert a few old ASP pages to ASP.Net and have run into a problem. In one of the pages, the previous coder set up a way to list items from a database that a user searches for using HTML tags. I know that in ASP HTML can be distinguished in functions by using the <% operator. I was wondering: is there anything like this in ASP.Net that I can use to set up the same listing capabilities?

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty new to ASP.NET, but I think that the <% operator distinguishes the code in ASP.NET.

Comment: When I tried that, I kept getting an error message saying that <% was not a valid character.